# Past tense of "I want to go away on a trip"

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs, past-simple

1. I wanted to go away on a trip this weekend.
2. I wanted to went away on a trip this weekend.

The second sentence sounds wrong, but why does "go away" not become "went away"?

Comment: An infinitive after a verb is always the basic form and this form is never changed.

Answer (score 1):

**Want** is the central verb in your sentence and its tense will define when the action occurred.

**To go** (infinitive) is part of the subordinate clause which indicates what you wanted to do.

> I **wanted** to go away this weekend, so I **went** to the countryside

Answer (score 0):

'to' is always followed by the [infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive#Uses_of_the_infinitive) form of a verb. 'Wanted' already indicates that the sentence is in the past tense.

Comment: Generally that's true, I can think of an exception though."I look forward to HEARING from you". in this case we use an ing form of the the verb.

Comment: @Maryam - Good observation, although I think it's because in that case, the gerund is functioning like a noun, not a verb.  So maybe it's more correct to say that in cases like "want to/need to/have to", we use the infinitive, but "look forward to" takes a noun, not a verb.